# LWC lightning-input - max-length attribute for text input not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

I have not been able to replicate this but we have an issue with the end-user where she entered more than the specified length for text input. The first name text field max-length was 15 but she was able to enter 16. I tried across browsers and OS but not able to hit the same issue. I used OOTB lightning-input component. Any suggestions or ideas? I was going to add additional length validation in JS to prevent this.

Note: I dont have any more info like browser or platform etc..

```
<lightning-input 
    id='firstName'
    data-key="firstName"
    type="text" 
    autocomplete="off"
    max-length ="15"
    label="First name"
    value={firstName}
    onchange={handleInput}
    class="firstNameCls"
    message-when-value-missing="Required input"
    required></lightning-input>
```

Comment: Please check that user have Java script enabled in the browser also check what are the different browser extension is installed. Once you confirm the latest version of the browser, JavaScript enabled and all extension disabled. You should see some difference. If it is IE check the document mode is EDGE or not

Comment: If you are on Firefox, this is likely to be the culprit: https://www.fxsitecompat.dev/en-CA/docs/2020/text-exceeding-maxlength-will-no-longer-be-truncated-when-pasted-into-input-or-textarea/ (maxlength no longer truncates the field) - although the valid property will be `false` and toolong will be `true`

Answer (score 0):

Change the lightning input attribute to maxlength="15"

so that would be in your scenario:

```
<lightning-input 
id='firstName'
data-key="firstName"
type="text" 
autocomplete="off"
maxlength="15"
label="First name"
value={firstName}
onchange={handleInput}
class="firstNameCls"
message-when-value-missing="Required input"
required></lightning-input>
```

For more information visit: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation

Comment: For those wondering what the difference is, OP uses "max-length" and this answer asserts that the attribute name is "maxlength" (no hyphen). It doesn't help that the documentation uses both (it's "max-length" in the specification tab and "maxlength" in the documentation tab).